# Storing QListWidget column widths

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I'm trying to store the widths of a <strike>QListWidget</strike> QTableWidget's columns. The user might adjust them as he wishes, but closing the app makes everything go back to 'normal' widths.

I've been trying to look for a 'columnResize' or 'resize' signal. But haven't seen something similar to it.

Comment: `QListWidget` and columns? It is a list. It has only one column. Do you mean `QTableWidget`?

Comment: Oops. Should have checked it's type first. I'll do some research on a QTableWidget now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean `QTreeWidget` rather than `QListWidget`, as the latter does not have columns. The widths of the columns can be retrieved like this:

```
columns = [tree.columnWidth(index) for index in range(tree.columnCount())]
```

You can then save this list when your application closes.

**EDIT**

NB: The same code will work with a QTableWidget.

Comment: It was a QTableWidget. I should have checked earlier. I'll try it out now.